# Почему служба Windows не может делать скриншоты?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-service

Есть консольное приложение ASP.NET Core (gRPC сервис). Одна из его задач отправка скриншотов в клиентское приложение на другом ПК с определенной периодичностью.

Если это приложение запускается просто двойным кликом, то все работает, но стоит только создать из него службу и запускать ее, то все сразу перестает работать (именно функция создания и отправки скриншотов).

Собственно вопрос: служба не имеет доступа к экрану? Почему? Если не существует видимого окна или иконки в трее, то ничего работать не будет или я что-то не понимаю?

Как это исправить?

Comment: зайдите в службы пуск - выполнить `services.msc` зайдите в свойства вашей службы и переключитесь на закладку `Вход в систему`. Тут настройте либо вход с системной учётной записью и разрешите взаимодействие с рабочим столом. ( второй вариант - попробовать учётную запись у которой есть права )

Comment: @alex Пробовал, не работает